# HTML5 MP4 video not working on iPad

Tags: video, html5-video

I'm having trouble getting some MP4 videos to play on iPad. The following works on Chrome and IE9 (with the addition of a meta tag) but it won't work on my iPad.

I read some posts that suggested not all MP4 videos will play on an iPad, but I actually pulled these MP4 videos from an iOS app created in-house where they play fine. I'm working with quite a few videos so I don't want to convert them unless I really have to.

Does it make sense to think that if they can play within a native app that they can play with HTML5 in a browser?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!-- the following line is required for the video to play in IE9 -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
<title>Video Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<video id="videoContent" controls="true"  autobuffer height="200" width="400">
   <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

BTW, I'm using an iPad 2 and iOS6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I broke down and converted the files to M4V and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried renaming your video to have ogg extension?

Comment: I renamed it to .ogg and it still doesn't work on my iPad. It does act differently though, just giving me a black box instead of a crossed out play symbol.